# Helm - Adding a character only if value is present

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have created a helm chart, Below is the snippet of the chart.

I will get value of gateway.contextpath from my values file.

`prefix: /{{ .Release.Name }}/{{ .Values.gateway.contextpath}}/`

There are few instances where gateway.contextpath are passed and few instances where the values are not passed. When values are passed, I get output as below

`prefix: /sample/hello/`

However, When the values are not passed, I see that */* is added.

`prefix: /sample//`

Is it possible to control adding */* based on the values file?

Answer (score 4):

You can define a function in **_helpers.tpl**, something like below

```
{{- define "superchart.getPath" -}}
{{- if .Values.gateway -}}
{{- if .Values.gateway.contextpath -}}
{{- printf "/%s/%s/" .Release.Name .Values.gateway.contextpath -}}
{{- else -}}
{{- printf "/%s/" .Release.Name -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- else -}}
{{- printf "/%s/" .Release.Name -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

And use it in your **deployment.yaml** (or any other file)

`prefix: {{ include "superchart.getPath" . }}`

Answer (score 3):

The [Go text/template language](https://godoc.org/text/template) has `{{ if }}...{{ end }}` conditionals and you can put almost arbitrary content inside of those.  The direct approach to what you've shown could be

```
prefix: /{{ .Release.Name -}}
  {{- if .Values.gateway.contextpath -}}
    /{{ .Values.gateway.contextpath -}}
  {{- end -}}
  /
```

Wherever there's a `-` inside the curly braces, it causes the template engine to consume all of the whitespace adjacent to it, so this should appear in a single string (even though it's written over five lines).

(Remember that you can use the `helm template` command to render a chart without actually submitting it to Kubernetes, which is helpful for debugging.)

The aesthetics of the template file can be tricky; there are other ways you can rearrange this to possibly be more readable.  Another alternative using a temporary variable:

```
{{- $p := .Values.gateway.contextpath }}
prefix: /{{ .Release.Name }}{{ if $p }}/{{ $p }}{{ end }}/
```

@edbighead's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59406923/10008173) breaking this out into a completely separate template is a good approach too: the `/path/part` URL layout is fairly visible there, compared to my suggestions here.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can be used to add leading slash if needed:

```
{{regexReplaceAll "^/*" .Values.ingress.context "/"}}
```

You can used it to normalize/deduplicate slashes in assembled path:

```
{{regexReplaceAll "^/*|/+" .Values.ingress.context "/"}}
```

Or, you can also enforce trailing slash:

```
{{regexReplaceAll "^/*|/+|/*$" .Values.ingress.context "/"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following is more readable?

```yaml
{{- if .Values.gateway.contextpath }}
          - prefix: /sample/{{ .Values.gateway.contextpath }}/
{{- else }}
          - prefix: /sample/
{{- end }}
```

I would prefer this than having to deal with it inside the prefix.